# Как сверстать черный фон как на картинке

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

макет ограничен по ширине но нужно что бы справа черный фон растягивался на всю длину окна. Надпись в макете а фон выходит за рамки.Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

**Flexbox** решение.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 180px;
}

.main-block {
  width: 200px; /* фиксированная ширина */
  background: pink;
  padding:10px;
}

.black-block {
  flex-grow: 1; /* разрешаем растяжку */
  background: black;
  color: white;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-block">Блок фиксированной ширины</div>
  <div class="black-block">Чёрный блок растягивающийся на всю ширину</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Есть одна проблема он растягивается по ширине родительского елемента а нужно до конца экрана

Comment: @Vlad467 в данном случае эти величины совпадают, если не брать margin у body

Comment: В вашем примере совпадают, а в примере автора нет.

Answer (score 0):

Задай `:after` цвет фона тот который тебе необходим

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

```
.box {
 position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #f00;
  &:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
  }
}
```